# Can't see trusted application provider in 'Software & Update'

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-center, ppa, gnupg

Can't see trusted application provider in 'Software & Update' after I did this:
I described everything I did in order.

I installed Y-PPA-Manager. Using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

then I opened Y-PPA-Manager and selected Advanced and then "try to import all missing GPG key".[image: Screenshot of the window]

After that process it didn't fix my missing public key problem with a PPA. Instead I got this:
[image: Screenshot of the "Software and Updates" after the attempted fix by Y-PPA-Manager]

There were many entry in this tab before. But "Software & Updates" is showing me a blank tab. But when I open filed manager and navigated to "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d" I found that all my gpg keys are there.[image: File manager]

Then I restart my computer but the issue seems to be parmanent. Will it be a serious problem or it's just a software glitch?